# Circular dependency on delete (EF core)

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two classes in my DB that reference each other, like in the example below.

`Parent` can have any number of `Child` objects, and I set a foreign key constraint to have `Child.ParentID` reference `Parent.ID`; setting `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` for the relation ensures that when a `Parent` is deleted all `Child` objects are deleted as well.

The problem is that I also need a reference to one of the `Child` objects in the `Parent` class, called `PreferredChild` in the example below. I was expecting that creating a constraint between `Parent.PreferredChildId` and `Child.ID` would work if I set `DeleteBehavior.SetNull`, but what actually happens is that when I delete a `Parent` object, if `PreferredChildID` is set, I get this exception:

*System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'Parent [Deleted] PreferredChild PreferredParent { 'PreferredChildID' } <- Child [Deleted] Parent Children { 'ParentID' } <- Parent [Deleted]'.'*

Is there a way to model this so that I can delete a `Parent` object without unsetting the `PreferredChildID` first?

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Parent {
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public int? PreferredChildID { get; set; }

    public virtual Child PreferredChild { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent PreferringParent { get; set; }
}

public class TestContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) {
        options.UseSqlite("Data Source=test.db");
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        // I would like to configure the model so that when a Parent is deleted, 
        // all Children are deleted. Using SetNull on PreferredChildID to avoid object
        // being deleted twice
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Child>()
            .HasOne(c => c.PreferringParent)
            .WithOne(p => p.PreferredChild)
            .HasForeignKey<Parent>(p => p.PreferredChildID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Child>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Parent)
            .WithMany(p => p.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        using (var context = new TestContext()) {
            var parent = new Parent();
            context.Parents.Add(parent);
            context.SaveChanges();
            var child1 = new Child { ParentID = parent.ID };
            var child2 = new Child { ParentID = parent.ID };
            context.Children.AddRange(child1, child2);
            context.SaveChanges();
            parent.PreferredChildID = child2.ID;
            context.SaveChanges();
            // This explodes
            context.Parents.Remove(parent);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So you are doing all this so that if the last child is deleted the parent is deleted aswell? Or why is LastChild there? Why not just `LastChild => Children.LastOrDefault();`

Comment: No, what I want is that when parent is deleted the children are deleted.

Comment: `LastChild` in this example is not the same that I have in my real code, and can be changed later, so the `LastOrDefault` trick wouldn't work. Maybe this naming is a bit misleading, I can update the example.

Comment: You want the last added child Id in the parent? Thats it? Why not use timestamps in the child instead? Edit: I see... PreferredChild makes more sense :) ... No that won't work... DB wise that would always cause problems... I suggest adding a third table with a 1:1 connection to preferred child and parent

Comment: Btw... Its horrible that your keys are nullable

Comment: In the real model I'm using `Guid`s, so I set them nullable to have the DB generate them.

Comment: You dont need to... Just set the HasDatabaseGeneratedOption to Identity and whatever value you have in your model will be replaced by the DB generated on insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Why not just do the following?</s>

```cs
public class Parent 
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public int? LastChildID => LastChild?.ID;

    public virtual Child LastChild => Children?.LastOrDefault();
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

---

Edit: After OP has edited his question, it's more clear what he wants.

I suggest adding a third table like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PreferredChilds] (
    [ParentId]     INT          NOT NULL,
    [PreferredChild] INT    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ParentId] ASC, [PreferredChild] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Parents] ([Id]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([PreferredChild]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Children] ([Id])
);
```

This way you don't have any problem with circular dependencies.
If you delete the parent, the entry in the `preferredchilds` and `children` table will also gets deleted.

Comment: I've udpated the question following your comment, changed "last" to preferred" to make it clear that it's not just the last added. Moreover, I need a column with the id of the preferred child in the parent table.